# Finding General solution to pde $u_x^2+u_y^2=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u_x^2+u_y^2=0$$

I'm having trouble trying to find a general solution to the pde
What I did so far was I rewrote it as $(d_x + d_y)u^2$. So I need to find when $d_x =-d_y$ Im just really stuck on where to go. I found a general solution by trial and error to be $Ae^{k(x-y)}$ where $k$ is an element of the reals.

Comment: Try separation of variables.

Comment: If $a^2+b^2=0$ what can you say about a and b?

Comment: That  a and b both have to be zero

Comment: True. I don't think the solution you gave can be a solution then.

Comment: Hi Paul, maybe I'm wrong but the but have you tried working it out.

Comment: Your pde is a sum of squares and, as you say, both terms must be 0 for all x and y. this simplifies things.

Comment: what do you exactly meant by $u_x^2$ ?

Comment: Your $Ae^{k(x-y)} $ gives $2A^2k^2e^{2k(x-y)}$ not 0

Comment: Sorry Paul, but  should it not be just k instead of k squared. And then i took the derivative with respect to y and  I got zero after adding them. My question really wasn't about my solution I was hoping that I could find a general solution in an easier way.

Comment: But you are squaring each derivative no? you can't add two squares and get 0, you said so yourself.

Comment: It's from a past mid term exam. But I thought when it was written like that it was meant as $(u^2)_x$?

Comment: I would have thought $(u_x)^2$, otherwise it reduces to $u(u_x+u_y)=0$ so that $u=0$ or $u_x+u_y$=0 and if so, why not just start with that first order pde?

Comment: I'm not sure why. But im stuck in trying to find the general solution that satisfies $u_x +u_y$ =0 I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with it

Comment: This is the standard first order wave equation which is probably done in your notes. I don't think this is the problem asked though!

Comment: Hi Paul, my apologies you were correct I had the wrong interpretation. There are no solutions to the PDE. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you misunderstood the ambiguous notation $u_x^2$ which meaning is usually $(u_x)^2$, not $(u^2)_x$. The sum of two positive reals is zero if and only if both are zero themselves. Therefore, for real $u$, the equation $u_x^2 + u_y^2 = 0$ implies that both partial derivatives vanish:
$$
u_x = 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad u_y = 0 .
$$
Therefore, $u(x,y) = c_1$ is constant.

Comment: This is the same approach I would have taken. It is also the easiest approach (+1).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a piece of cake.

$u_x^2+u_y^2=0$

$u_y^2=-u_x^2$

$u_y=\pm iu_x$

$u_y\mp iu_x=0$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$ , letting $y(0)=0$ , we have $y=t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\mp i$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=\mp it+x_0=\mp iy+x_0$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=0$ , letting $u(0)=f(x_0)$ , we have $u(x,y)=f(x_0)=f(x\pm iy)$